# захват границ в регулярных выражениях Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть задание, вырезать предложения из текста. Я использовал метод
`.split()` и указал символы границы разбивки `"\\.|\\...|\\?|\\!"`, но столкнулся с тем, что символ окончания предложения не захватывается. Как указать границу, включая знак окончания предложения?
Хочу ***Предложение!*** Получаю ***Предложение***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не встречал такого метода. Немного топорно, но можно добавить какой-то спец.символ после каждого завершения предложения, а потом по этому спецсимволу разбить:

```
String str = new String();
List<String> regExprs = new ArrayList<>();
regExprs.add("\\.{3}");
regExprs.add("\\.{1} ");
regExprs.add("\\!");
regExprs.add("\\?");
for (String s :regExprs) {
    str = str.replaceAll(s, s + "^");
}
String[] result = str.split("\\^");
```

Answer (score 0):

В классе `String` есть метод  `String[] split(String regex, int limit)`, второй параметр которого означает максимальное количество элементов в итоговом массиве. При отрицательном значении `limit` (например -1) последний разделитель также захватывается.
Вообще-то этот метод и с более привычным одним параметром `String[] split(String regex)` все равно вызывает метод `String[] split(String regex, int limit)`, только там `limit` = 0, т.е. работает без захвата последнего разделителя.